# Succeed use ORMLite for SQLite in Windows, but failed in Mac

Tags: java, jdbc, ormlite

I've implement an application, it works when I code in Windows. But the same code gave Exception in Mac. I use SQLite database and have put sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar as library.

I know the driver went ok since I have check it like below:

```
public static void pureSqlite() throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:hadits-bukhari.sqlite";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connection established.");

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM hadits";
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    int i = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (i == 5) break;

        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("nomer")+". "+resultSet.getString("deskripsi"));

        i++;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when I used my Windows computer.

Then, I've implement it with ORMLite's way. Create Hadits class with required annotation. Then I have below function:

```
public static void withOrmLite() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); // even put this test
    System.out.println("Frankly, class org.sqlite.JDBC is exists."); 

    Ilmu ilmu = new IlmuImpl();
    List<Hadits> list = ilmu.findHadits("bukhari", "");
    int i = 0;
    for (Hadits item: list) {
        if (i == 10) break;
        System.out.println(item.number+". "+item.desc);
        i++;
    }
}
```

From IlmuImpl:

```
@Override
public List<Hadits> findHadits(String book, String keyword) throws Exception {
    String dbHost = "jdbc:sqlite:hadits-"+book+".sqlite";
    ConnectionSource connection = new JdbcConnectionSource(dbHost);
    Dao<Hadits, Long> haditsDao = DaoManager.createDao(connection, Hadits.class);

    List<Hadits> list;

    if (keyword == null || keyword.trim().length() == 0) {
        list = haditsDao.queryForEq("buku", book);
    } else {
        QueryBuilder<Hadits, Long> queryBuilder = haditsDao.queryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.where().like("deskripsi", "%"+keyword+"%");
        PreparedQuery<Hadits> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
        list = haditsDao.query(preparedQuery);
    }


    connection.close();
    return list;
}
```

This code do fine in Windows, but failed when I use the same code in Mac, says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Driver class was not found for SQLite database.  Missing jar with class org.sqlite.JDBC.
at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:27)
at com.j256.ormlite.db.BaseDatabaseType.loadDriver(BaseDatabaseType.java:47)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.initialize(JdbcConnectionSource.java:137)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.<init>(JdbcConnectionSource.java:117)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.<init>(JdbcConnectionSource.java:59)
at ilmu.implementation.IlmuImpl.findHadits(IlmuImpl.java:17) <-- this is my class
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
...
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

The exception is trying to tell you all that you need to know.  Although you say that you "put sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar as library", the `JDBC` class is not found.  This means that there is something wrong with your classpath.

Either the library hasn't been added to the right directory or hasn't been properly identified as a dependency in your IDE, maven, or other build utility.  If you give more details about your build environment, I can provide more specifics about tuning the dependencies.

Comment: Hi Gray,
I don't think there is a problem with my classpath. As you can see above, I've put a check like:

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); // even put this test
    System.out.println("Frankly, class org.sqlite.JDBC is exists.");

And the console simply shows "Frankly, class org.sqlite.JDBC is exists."

Comment: Any chance you are inside of some sort of web container @AmriShodiq that has changed your classpath?  Take a look at the ORMLite code and all it is doing is a `Class.forName("...")` as well.

Comment: No, I don't code for web base other than PHP. And I believe the problem is not the classpath.